# Firebase Console Database Rules : how to index the following database structure in Database Rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

The example is parking spaces listing in a country.
The reason to structure the database with a userParkingDistanceMap is sorting by distance between the current user and all parking spaces.

The database query is `.orderByChild("userParkingDistanceMap/" + getUid())`.

So, how could I index this `userParkingDistanceMap`in Database Rules?

```js
"parkingSpacesTokyo" : {
    "parkingId5" : {
      "parkingName" : "MY-PARKING-NAME",
      "parkingQuantity" : 70,
      "userParkingDistanceMap" : {
        "uid-uid-uid-uid-uid-uid-uid" : 7983,
        "9EAiImOh4ZUnqJ7em51u81FukD73" : 9456,
        "AG84p8KJgANuobRJ5pn1ipxULFB3" : 8336,
        "yYLVffMFsBQhsGHNWuPOksMDgip2" : 7983,
        "yp6mZm2SPVhz5pOq57tSEZ40piJ2" : 7983
      }
    },
   "parkingId6": {
        ...
    }
},
"parkingSpacesYOKOHAMA" : {

}
```

Comment: seems too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you might have initialized the reference by something like

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("parking");


ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListner);
```

where valueEventListner is:

```
ValueEventListner valueEventListner = new ValueEventListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
         {
         for(DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot: dataSnapshot)
             {
             DatabaseReference parkindId = ref.child(dataSnapshot.getKey);
             for(DataSnapshot parkingIdSnapshot : childDataSnapshot)
                {
                if(parkindIdSnapshot.hasChildren())
                   {
                   for(DataSnapshot distanceMap : parkingIdSnapshot)
                      {
                      String value = distanceMap.getValue(String.class);
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
         }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
         {}
    });
```

Well I just wrote this code in direct answer so it's kind of psudo code so basically you might have got the idea about it. Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is Database Rules indexing in Firebase console